# Magento 2 - Buy X Get Y Free isn't working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Is anyone know anything about this functionality? I'm trying to set up the functionality with the following guide:
[magento docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html)

It isn't working...

Comment: what did you do ? add screenshot

Comment: All the same as in the magento2 docs above - in configuration.
At the frontend side - I add product with qty 3 and go to cart\checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Buy X` meaning you have to Pay for X.

Now, let's take X = 2, Y = 1, price = $5. Buy 2 get 1 free.

Meaning, you have to `Spend money` or `pay` for 2 `= 10$`, now `you are having 2 product in hand` and store will give you 1 free => You are `having 3 products` in total.

So in this case, we have to put 3 in cart (3 = X + Y) to get Y free.

Another example: Buy 6 get 3 => you have to put 9 products in cart.